# Didn't understand relationship 'LinkedEntityId' in field path

Tags: salesforce, document, apex

So I am generally able to query the relationships but I do not have the access to this object in object manager, so what should be the query to access accountId from ContentDocumentLink object when I know LinkedEntity is a case.

My Code:

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> case_file_links=
  [
  SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId.AccountId,ShareType
  FROM ContentDocumentLink
    WHERE Id IN: case_file_link_Ids
  ];
```

Error:

```
  SELECT Id,ContentDocumentId,LinkedEntityId.AccountId,ShareType
                              ^
ERROR at Row:2:Column:45
Didn't understand relationship 'LinkedEntityId' in field path. If you..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinkedEntityId` is a weird mutant lookup to many tables, any table that supports File upload. Official name is "[polymorphic lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm)".

Maybe you worked with Tasks before, they have similar fields. `WhatId` can point to Account, Case, Opportunity plus many custom objects. and `WhoId` points to User/Contact/Lead.

So it's a lookup to "something". It's not guaranteed it's to Cases so at compile time SF can't just blindly accept `AccountId`. What if the field is not there.

You might have to use [`TYPEOF`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_typeof.htm) in SOQL.

```
SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ShareType,
    TYPEOF LinkedEntity WHEN Case THEN CaseNumber, Subject, AccountId END
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE Id IN ('06A7a000001VafmEAC', '06A7a000001VafnEAC')
```

Developer Console is too stupid to display it properly but [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) should manage

[image]

In Apex you'll need an [`instanceof`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm) to check and cast the LinkedEntity to right sObject... or use the generic `sObj.get('AccountId')` and if it's not there it'll return null?

If this sounds like too much hassle - you can always split it into 2 queries.

1. Query just `SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId, ShareType FROM ContentDocumentLink`
2. Loop through results, collect `LinkedEntityId` into a helper `Set<Id>`.
3. `Map<Id, Case> cases = new Map<Id, Case>([SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :mySet]);`

Comment: I realize that an  extra map is surely a feasible solution, but I will try the sObj.get('AccountId') solution and get back to you.